# Class App\Http\Controllers\ManagerLoginController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, controller, laravel-6

I have been making a custom multi-auth and got the following error:

> Class App\Http\Controllers\ManagerLoginController does not exist

I have been searching for this error but couldn't find the solution. I have attached the screenshot from my controller in the directory.

[image]

**ManagerLoginController.php**

```php
class ManagerLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showManagerLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login', ['url' => 'manager']);
    }

    public function managerLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:8'
        ]);

        if (Auth::guard('manager')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password],
            $request->get('remember'))) {

            return redirect()->intended('login/manager');
        }

        return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/manager/login', 'ManagerLoginController@showManagerLoginForm')->name('manager.login');
Route::post('/manager/login', 'ManagerLoginController@managerLogin');
Route::get('/manager/register', 'ManagerRegisterController@showManagerRegisterForm')->name('manager.register');
Route::post('/manager/register', 'ManagerRegisterController@createManager');
Route::get('/manager', 'ManagersController@redirectAuthenticatedManager');
```

Comment: you namespace should be  `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

Comment: I ve left a space in `Route::get('/somelink', ' MyController@aFunction');` before `MyController`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since ManagerController is not in root Controllers you need to specify namespace in your routes.

```
Route::namespace('Auth')->group(function () {
   Route::get('/manager/login','ManagerLoginController@showManagerLoginForm')->name('manager.login');
   Route::post('/manager/login', 'ManagerLoginController@managerLogin');
   Route::get('/manager/register', 'ManagerRegisterController@showManagerRegisterForm')->name('manager.register');
   Route::post('/manager/register', 'ManagerRegisterController@createManager');
}
```

It is my mistake. I thought your controllers are located in Auth folder. As others have already answered, the namespace in your controller should be without Auth.

Comment: if you have updated your namespaces run ``` composer dump-autoload```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your namespace. you are using namespace `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;` but your controller in `App\Http\Controllers` directory. So either change the namespace or move the controller to the `Auth` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue turns out I had misspelled the name of the controller, if you're here and you can't figure out what the issue is I suggest you double-check your names, just to be sure.

~Regards

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is just as simple as : `php artisan route:clear` , then the problem is fixed, at least that's what worked for me